# Which of my moths have an extra long proboscis?

Tags: flutter-starlight

The owl wants me to send out a moth with an extra long proboscis. Problem is, I have a lot of moths now, and I don't know which one fits that requirement as I haven't leveled them all enough to get their fact (which is where I figure this information would be).

Which moths fit that requirement?

Comment: Allow me to make inappropriate use of this comment box to say, WAT?

Comment: @ender I really don't know what is so wat about this

Comment: It's an extremely esoteric question so I thought the WAT would be funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Sweet Potato Hornworm fits the requirements.

Comment: So it does. That is perfect, I have been waiting do long to complete this.